# Datagridview bind Comboboxcolumns to changing list

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I am trying to use a datagridview as userinput in a windows forms project. The user should be able to add new comboboxcolumns and also edit existing columns (changing, adding, deleting items).

For now I have a List of "Features"

```
public class Feature
{
    public Guid featureID { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; } 
    public List<Choice> choices { get; set; } 
}

public class Choice
{
    public String choiceID { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }        
}
```

The user is able to create new features and edit existing ones. The features are then added to a list. 
For every List Item there should be a comboboxcolumn in a datagridview.

When the user adds a new Feature I create the Column with the following Code:

```
private void addColumnToTable(Feature ft)
    {
        String colName = "column" + ft.name;

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        col.HeaderText = ft.name;
        col.Name = colName;
        col.DataSource = ft.choices;
        col.ValueMember = "choiceID";
        col.DisplayMember = "name";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
    }
```

This works perfectly.
The user is now able to add input to the databoxcolumn. 
Lets say the user selects an item in one column and later decides to delete or update the selected choice. Then I get an error, because the selected item doesn't exist anymore. 
I don't want to delete the changed column and add it again, because I want the selection of unchanged Choices to be the same before and after the Feature edit.

How can I update existing columns? Is it possible to databind my featurelist to the datagridview to achieve the desired behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: So, you want to dynamically add columns to a DataGridView. Is my understanding correct? Apparently, your code to add the column seems to work. What you're saying is if the user edits or deletes the "value" in that new column later on, then you get "an error". Is that also correct? Please provide what the exact error message is, and confirm if my understanding is good about your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, whenever you modify your `ComboBox` list options you should:

- Nullify your `Column.DataSource` to invalidate the UI.
- Set your `Column.DataSource` to your modified list.
- Reset the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` - otherwise it'll bind to the *whole object* and not *properties of the object*.

```
currentColumn.DataSource = null;
currentColumn.DataSource = modifiedChoices; // List<Choice>
currentColumn.ValueMember = "choiceID";
currentColumn.DisplayMember = "name";
```

Now you have options - both of which are to nullify the invalid value(s):

1. Loop through the cells of that column.

   ```
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
       if (row.Index != this.dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
       {
           string value = row.Cells[col.Name].Value.ToString();

           if (!modifiedChoices.Any(item => item.choiceID == value))
           {
               row.Cells[col.Name].Value = null;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Handle the `DataGridView.DataError` event as the error dialogue suggests.

   ```
   this.dataGridView1.DataError += DataGridView1_DataError;

   private void DataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
   {
       if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
       {
           this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = null;
           e.Cancel = true;
       }
   }
   ```